# What Components might these Be?

Tags: msp430, battery-operated

I've been researching on backup power system for embedded devices that must run uninterrupted on mains or backup.

I was trying to study an energy meter board i have with me and came upon a circuit i was unable to analyse completely.
[image]
The system is an energy meter running on TI's [MSP430F4793](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f4793.pdf). The circuit runs on 3.2VDC, and seams to use the MSP's SVS module (Supply Voltage Supervisor) to monitor battery voltage, because the a voltage divider from the battery goes to the input of the SVS module (SVSIN). 
pin1 of Q1 is fed with 4V from the main power supply before it is regulated to 3.2volts, while pin2 of Q2 is fed from the backup battery rated at 3.6Volts.
I want to have an understanding of how the circuit works, but i cannot see the name of componets Q1 and Q2.

When on mains power, the

I got the following readins for Q1:
pin1 reads 4Volts, 
     pin 2 reads 3.6Volts, and
 
      Pin3 reads 3.2Volts

FOR Q2:
pin1 reads 3.6Volts, 
pin2 reads 3.6V
 and pin3 reads 3.2V

On battery power, i get the following readins:
Q1:
pin1 reads 2.6Volts, 
     pin 2 reads 3.0Volts, and
 
      Pin3 reads 3.0Volts

Q2:
pin1 reads 3.0Volts, 
     pin 2 reads 3.6Volts, and
 
      Pin3 reads 3.0Volts

From the figure bellow, and the voltage readings above, can anyone determine what the Q1 and Q2 might be and how this circuit switches power?

Q1 is pulled up to 4V by the resistor marked 205

**edit**
I believe the circuit is designed to switch between mains voltage and battery backup. the 4VDC which comes from a regulator is dropped to about 3.2V via a diode which then connects to VCC. components like indicator LEDS, optical communication and relays on the circuit are fed from the same 4VDC via a separate diode so they are not powered by the battery when mains is not there.

Comment: Seems like BJT transistors to me. Are there any markings on Q1 and Q2?

Comment: all i see is SC1 followed by a Chinese character

Comment: Ah, [codebook](http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/mainframe.htm) does not seem to have it.

Comment: Isn't listed in [Turuta](http://www.turuta.md/smd2011.html) either.

Comment: You've added a few components on the power side, but I'm not interested in that; I have some idea what that should look like. I want to know what's connected to SVSIN.

Comment: @stevenvh the node between R2 and R3 in the diagram above go straight to SVSIN, and nothing else!

Answer (score 4):

If bottom left is base, top collector, and bottom right emitter (as is [often the case](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC847_BC547_SER.pdf) for SOT23 BJT transistors) then it's 2 NPN transistors forming a Darlington. That Darlington is in common collector.

The Darlington seems to pump current into the battery (without any limiting resistor), and a tiny current flows through the 30\$\Omega\$/2.2M\$\Omega\$ resistors. The battery voltage goes almost completely to SVSIN.

If the battery voltage is low enough (4V - 2 B-E junctions) the 4V will supply a tiny base current to the Darlington through the 2M\$\Omega\$. If the transistors have an \$H_{FE}\$ around 100 this will supply a few mA to the battery. Once charged the base current will drop to almost zero and the current to the battery will drop to trickle charge level.

**edit**
OK, that was a nice story, with some assumptions, but if the battery is not rechargeable, as *TiOLUWA* says in a comment below, there's not enough here to know the function of the Darlington. The battery has another function than just being monitored by the SVS, so there must be circuitry connected to SVSIN. I can't tell more without seeing more of the schematic.

Comment: If it's really a Darlington (it seems to me also) then it would be only useful to add two voltage drops from the 4V, isn't it?

Comment: 4VDC and VCC or separated by a diode

Comment: the batteries are not rechargeable, they are 3.6V Lithium batteries and its clearly stated "do not recharge", which means the circuit is not designed to recharge the batteries but to switch between mains and battery.

Comment: @TiOLUWA I don't see how do you switch the battery, since it's hard connected to the load.

Comment: @clabacchio the battery is separated from the load by the Q1 - Q2 connection. the power to the main ICs on the board are via the VCC line

Comment: @TiOLUWA I don't think so. Can you please explain what is connected to the 4VDC, Vcc and SVSIN? Because if the load is connected to SVSIN, then the battery IS connected to it via a resistor.

Comment: 4VDC coming from the power supply meets two diodes, one leads to VCC, the other serves 3LEDs and an optical interface.
the positive of the battery is fed directly into the SVSIN pin of the MCU (this is the input of the Supply Voltage Supervisor peripheral in the MCU) via the voltage divider shown in the diagram, and also meets the bottom left pin of Q2. that is all the connection made directly with the Battery.
The rest of the circuit is powered via VCC.

Comment: @TiOLUWA - You don't have to *tell* all this, *show* it! clabacchio and I have told you all we can derive from the part you've shown, and not without having to guess. Show more of the schematic.

Comment: i've edited the diagram, i hope its better now. I'm drawing it out from the board, i don't have the schematic.

Answer (score 2):

The schematic seems to not have any logic disposition of the components. But Q1 and Q2 are most likely transistor (drawn as packages for some reason), not specified if bipolars or FETs.

As a side note, if they really are transistors, there is no guarantee that the upper pins are the Base/Gate pins, and calling them `pin n` is not that meaningful.

Update: According to the last informations, I see it this way:

Vcc is lowered to 3.2 V when the supply is connected, so it shouldn't recharge the battery because of the lower voltage. It won't drain current either, because of the diode is reversed if the DC supply is lower or disconnected.

BUT I wouldn't rely on the lower voltage to avoid charging the battery, because if its voltage drops below 3.2 V (low battery), it will be recharged by the supply with the risk of damaging it.

Comment: but if they are FETS, then is it always Gate and Source down, and Drain at the top?

Comment: i've edited the question. there are actually diodes the separte the 4VDC from Vcc, droping it to about 3.2Volts.